# Skip processing files during Gradle build

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, libpng

I'm in the process of migrating my build system from ANT to Gradle (as ANT/ADT is now no longer supported by Google) and I ran into an issue in one of the test packages. There is a test that works with an empty png (as if somebody ran 'touch empty.png') and a corrupted png. These png files are in our res/drawable-hdpi folder, as they should be. When building though, Gradle uses libpng to do some sort of processing and it errors on these two files.

My question is: can I tell Gradle to skip processing on these two files, or is there another way to get around this issue?

BTW, on a whim I tried to rename the files to .xml (the only other allowed format) and, still, it wouldn't parse.

Comment: What if you moved those files out of res?

Comment: The files still need to be used in some of the tests.  If I moved them out of res, where could they so so they can still be accessed?

Comment: Files like this should usually be in src/test/resources. It's a good idea to refactor your codebase to use maven's directory structure (which gradle also recommends).

Answer (score 1):

To give an answer to others who find this question, I used horatius' answer and made the /res/raw directory and put my corrupted and empty png files in there.  Gradle didn't try and process them and they still get indexed by R.java.